# XNA a Simple 2D Point Light

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, shader, light

i want to make a 2D Point Light , in XNA, i was able to find some helpful information but is too advance for me , since i dont know nothing about Shaders

http://www.soolstyle.com/2010/02/15/2d-deferred-lightning

so my best aproximation is use a texture and use alpha blending, but im not happy with this result

so i was wondering, what is the most simple method to make a simple 2d point light?, if is there some Code examples, better

Comment: The simplest method is a texture overlay or something. The other option is shaders. Read the tutorial you linked to again, it has plenty of code examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can see a great example of how to do simple 2d lighting using XNA here at Shawn Hargreave's blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/01/02/spritebatch-and-custom-blend-modes.aspx

> "With multiplicative blending, I can draw a couple of rotated copies
>   of this sprite over my scene. Note how the light isn't just drawn as
>   white, but actually brightens up whatever scenery lies behind it:"